# Importing a data set in python

Tags: python

I am writing a code that requires me to import a set of data. Where in my python folder do I save the data so that the program will recognize it?

Here is a snippit from my code:

```
 from matplotlib.pylab import *
 from scipy import optimize

 # Read in the data, storing it as two 1D arrays, time and speed
 freefall=loadtxt('freefall.data')
 time  = freefall[:,0]
 speed = freefall[:,1]
```

The data file that I am trying to import is freefall.data.

Comment: Have you tried running your script from the same directory that `'freefall.data'` is in?

Comment: You shouldn't be putting your Python programs, or the data that they need, in your Python folder. Put them somewhere in your user home folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can load `'freefall.data'` if you put it in the same directory from which you execute your script.

Comment: I'm extremely new to python. How do I know which directory my script is running from?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the file in your current [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

---

If you're planning to always run your script from the command line rather than double-clicking it, and never run it without first `cd`ing into the directory it lives in, and never do `os.chdir` inside your code, and so on, then you can count on the working directory being the directory the script itself is in, so you can just place the data file next to the script and your script will find it.

---

But if those things are not all true, then there's really nowhere you can put it that will work. If your current working directory can be anywhere, then `freefall.data` has to be put everywhere!

So, if you want to handle those cases, you have to change your code.

Put this at the top of your script:

```
import os
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Then load the file like this:

```
freefall=loadtxt(os.path.join(scriptdir, 'freefall.data'))
```

Now, `freefall.data` will always be looked for in the same directory as the script, no matter how you run the script. So, just put it there.